Spring Boot backend/MySQL/React frontend - Cross-Site/Same-Site issue
I have built a Spring Boot backend, with React frontend and use a MySQL database. On my local machine, this works perfectly. I have then attempted to deploy on AWS using RDS for the Database, ElasticBeanstalk for the Spring Boot and S3 bucket for the React.
I have used JWT and have a controller /get-csrf, which issues a token. Login works fine and I can complete all GET requests without issue, however POST/PUT requests receive an error that references a Same-Site issue with a cross site response. (I have tested all endpoints with Postman and all work fine).
Will making use of AWS CloudFront resolve this issue or can someone point me in the right direction as to what I am missing?
Or would I be better off trying to find a host that will store the Spring Boot and React elements on the same server?
I have the following for securityFilterChain:
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                        .ignoringRequestMatchers("/api/auth/**", "/api/csrf-token")
        );
        
        http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()));
        
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")  // Only allow users with ADMIN role to access admin paths
                .requestMatchers("/api/manager/**").hasRole("MANAGER")  // Only allow users with MANAGER role to access manager paths
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/public/**", "/api/csrf-token","/**").permitAll() // Permit all to access public auth endpoints
                .anyRequest().authenticated()  // Require authentication for all other requests
        );

        http.addFilterBefore(authTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.exceptionHandling((exception)-> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler));

        return http.build();
    }




and this for CORS:
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();

    corsConfig.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList(frontendUrl));

    corsConfig.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "PATCH"));

    corsConfig.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

    corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfig.setMaxAge(3600L);

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);
    return source;
}

Then these are the errors:
error 1
error 2
I have tried to use various snippets of code I found online while searching for a solution but struggled to get anything that made a difference including in:
http.headers(headers -> headers
        .defaultsDisabled()
        .httpStrictTransportSecurity(hsts -> hsts.includeSubDomains(true).preload(true))
        .frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin)
        .xssProtection(xss -> xss.block(true))
);

adding a filter:
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws java.io.IOException, jakarta.servlet.ServletException {
        if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpResponse.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "your-cookie-name=value; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None");
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

I have tried various iterations of editing cookies but those also made no difference.
